# Should I use a capital L List for type hinting in Python 3.9+?

Tags: python, python-typing

In Python 3.9+ I can write `list_of_integers: list[int]`, but I see senior developers using the older syntax (even in Python 3.9 and 3.10 scripts):

```
from typing import List

list_of_integers: List[int]
```

Is this superior for backwards compatibility and explicitness?

Comment: [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) _deprecates_ the `typing` versions of those collections, but that's obviously not backwards compatible (unless [evaluation of annotations is postponed](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) you'll get a `TypeError`). Everything else is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Note that if you do `from __future__ import annotations`, `list[int]` is compatible with Python 3.7 and 3.8 as well.

Comment: Thank you, all! The context is a natural language processing project on AWS lambdas, but I think it should be runnable in Python 3.9. Sometimes our stack migrates or gets passed on as legacy code. I think the deprecation @SorousH and all mentioned is pretty clear typing.List --> list[] built in, so the examples I saw may just be habit from experienced programmers.

Comment: Is this really opinion-based? I'm voting to reopen since it sounds like it's basically unambiguously better to use the lowercase versions, based on the discussion here. Maybe the title could be framed a bit less opinion-based sounding, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the current version of [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) for `typing.List` says:

> *Deprecated since version 3.9*: `builtins.list` now supports `[]`. See PEP
> 585 and Generic Alias Type.

It should be considered best practice unless you have a compelling reason not to use it (like what you said about backward compatibility for older versions of Python).